# Unicode for mobile device

Tags: php, unicode, sms

Friend , I have a php code to send sms to mobile.It is working properly but the problem is.
If I try to send the following sms;
Hi
good

The result on mobile phone looks like : Hi_good

It just mix and shows only in one sentence on mobile phones..it seems there is a UNICODE problem.
So how to convert specific string to mobile sms support UNICODE.

Comment: Kindly share your piece of code here. So that we can suggest you the proper way according to your code.

Comment: @durgesh  show us your code to enable us to help you out or should we assume what part of your code is causing this issue?